# How prometheus rule evaluation works?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

Below is the prometheus rule:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: k8s
    role: alerting-rules
  name: prometheus-alerting-rules
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  groups:
  - name: heyservicedown4
    rules:
    - alert: Heyservicedown4
      annotations:
        description: abcd
        troubleshooting: https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/master/runbook.md
      expr: |
        sum(up{job="hey-service",namespace="xyz"}) == bool 3
      for: 1s
      labels:
        severity: pager
```

---

Upon deleting pods with label `job="hey-service"` multiple times,

only one(`ALERTS{alertname="Heyservicedown4"}` gives value 1) alert is raised.

Doesn't alert rule evaluation(every second - `for: 1s`) trigger an alert, upon failure of condition given in `expr`? Why only one alert is raised, when the rule `expr` fails every second(`for: 1s`)?

Comment: What do you mean about 'failure of condition'? If expr returns no results no alert will fire

Comment: @aclowkay `sum(up{job="hey-service",namespace="xyz"}) == bool 3` gives result as `false`

Comment: perhaps removing the ‘bool’ operator will solve this problem. Im not sure Prometheus will treat ‘false’ like ‘null’

Comment: `for: 1s` means that `expr` must resolve to an output vector element *at least for 1s*. That doesn't make too much sense usually, as rules are (per default) evaluated every 1m only.